# Adding GridView dynamically

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to show data in tabular form. But the problem is that the number of tables shown on the activity will be dynamic. Lets say there are 4 users in database, I'll be showing 4 tables each one containing data of one user.

I have tried to programmatically add table to my LinearLayout. But absolutely nothing is shown on the page. Here is the code that I am using for table:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow( this );
tr.setLayoutParams(newTableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

/* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
Button b = new Button( this );
b.setText("Dynamic Button");
b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

/* Add Button to row. */
tr.addView(b);

/* Add row to TableLayout. */
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(getActivity());
tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout_schoolAssignments);
linearLayout.addView(tl);
```

I also considered using GridView. But I couldn't find out a way of programatically adding row to the grid without using GridviewAdapter.
I am looking for somthing like this:

```
GridView gv = new GridView( this );
GridRow gr = /* Some code here */;

gv.addRow( gr );

linearLayout.addView( gv );
```

Does such a simple way exist?

Comment: adding data to gridview you must and should use any adapter.

Comment: @Praveena_Pinki Can you please help me figure out why isn't the row added dynamically to the table is not visible for me? Am I doing somthing wrong?